# Finding tokens within a string using a searching loop JAVA

Tags: java, token

So basically I'm trying to write a method that takes 2 strings as parameters and returns a boolean. It returns true if t occurs as a token within s, and returns false if otherwise.

I'm pretty new to coding so I don't really know what i'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
public static boolean containsToken(String s, String t) {

 Scanner scr = new Scanner(s);
```

This scanner breaks up String s into tokens

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
```

I tried to make this for loop search through the length of s for tokens that match up with String t

```
if(t.contains(scr.next()))

return true;
}
return false; 


}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of `s` and `t` for which `containsToken` should return `true`?

Comment: `This scanner breaks up String s into tokens` Are you sure scanner is changing the value of s? You're not just iterating the characters of the string passed?

Comment: @ernest_k     assertTrue(containsTokens("xyx xyy xyz xyz", "xyz");

Comment: @dustytrash could you elaborate? Sorry i'm very new to this.

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and output in your question.

Comment: @AxaLaxa What's wrong with the `contains()` String function? Given your example, assertTrue(`"xyx xyy xyz xyz".contains("xyz"))` passes. No need to write your own function

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is predominantly used for taking inputs from a stream like system.in.  Since you are provided with the whole string from the start you can tokenize it however fits your need with split